# select top 5 scores for each team

Tags: mysql, sql

This is different from the one marked as a double, I want to sum up top 5 for each team. The double post takes out for each of the results in separate rows.

I'm using this question now but it seems that SQL is randomly returning 5 of for exasmple 10 rows and sum up, not the top 5. Anyone has some input for me?

select team, sum(length) as totalScore
from
   (SELECT t.*,
       @num_in_group:=case when @team!=team then @num_in_group:=0 else @num_in_group:=@num_in_group+1 end as num_in_group,
       @team:=team as t
    FROM reg_catches t, (select @team:=-1, @num_in_group:=0) init
    ORDER BY team asc) sub
WHERE sub.num_in_group<=4 and competition = 16 and team = 25
GROUP BY team
ORDER BY totalScore DESC;

I'm struggeling on a SQL question that I can't get my head around. My result-table looks like below, I'm trying to sum up the top 5 result for each team and limit the output to the top 3 highest ranked teams. Everything was working as expected until I added my last score in the result-table. The output of my SQL now is randomly for team 25. I've expected that to be 520..

```
team length competition
----------------------
26   70       16
25   70       16
25   95       16
25   98       16
25   100      16
25   100      16
25   100      16
25   122      16
```

Output:

```
team totalScore
---- -----------
25  122
26  70
```

Wanted output:

```
team totalScore
---- -----------
25  522
26  70


SELECT team, SUM(length) AS totalScore
FROM(
  SELECT team, length
  FROM table_result m
  WHERE competition = 16 and (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM table_result mT
    WHERE mT.team = m.team AND mT.length >= m.length
    ) <= 5) tmp
GROUP BY team
ORDER BY totalScore DESC Limit 3
```

Anyone has any ideas for me?

Comment: This problem is made unnecessarily complicated by your failure to include a PRIMARY KEY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select team, sum(length) 
from
   (SELECT t.*,
       @num_in_group:=case when @team!=team then @num_in_group:=0 else @num_in_group:=@num_in_group+1 end as num_in_group,
       @team:=team as t
    FROM test.table_result t, (select @team:=-1, @num_in_group:=0) init
    ORDER BY team, length desc) sub
WHERE sub.num_in_group<=4
GROUP BY team
```

Comment: This is just perfect! Thanks for your quick respons and the solution!

Comment: Hi! I have problem with this query now when we're live with the site.. :(

It seems that the query returns random 5 results and sums up this, I would like it to sum up the top 5..

Anyone has any idea for me?

Answer (score 0):

You should use a window function to accomplish this. Here's an example query:

```
SELECT team, SUM(length) AS totalScore FROM
  (SELECT team,
          length,
          row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY team ORDER BY length desc) AS rowNumber
   FROM table_result) tmp
WHERE rowNumber <= 5
AND competition = 16
GROUP BY team
ORDER BY totalScore DESC
LIMIT 3;
```

This query has two parts.

The inner query uses the `row_number()` window function to give every row an extra column that indicates its rank. `PARTITION BY team` says that the rank should be kept separately for each team, so that you end up being able to select the top `n` scores for every team.

The outer query uses a `GROUP BY` on the result of the inner query to take the `SUM`, per team, of all of the scores whose row number is less than or equal to 5 - in other words, the top 5 scores.

Comment: MySQL doesn't have window functions, that's SQL-Server.

Comment: Thanks for your help, as said above this doesn't work with my MariaDB, but the help is much appreciated anyway and hopefully it will help someone else! Best regards, Christian